# Update and Select MYSQL, Convert Unixtime to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Got a minor issue, im working on a old old database layout that i did not do my self.

The one hu created it used Unix Timestamps for everything, now i want to converte this in to a normal MySQL Timestamp, i know i can do the from_unixtimestam function.

But what i need is actually to crap the unix timestamp from a column called last_login and converte it to timestamp and then save this value to last_login_sql

How the heck would i do this?

Table name: kunstner
Column name of unix timestamp: last_login
Column name of timestamp: last_login_sql

There is id column ofc.

Hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for saving the new value, something like this should work:

```
UPDATE kunstner SET last_login_sql = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login)
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please select it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
DECLARE My_Timestamp TIMESTAMP ;

SELECT from_unixtime(<source_column_name>)
  INTO My_Timestamp 
  FROM <your_table_name>
 WHERE ....
```